# UP! Получение символа нажатой клавиши - C++

Tags: c++, клавиатура, sfml

... Здравствуйте ... Весь вечер "бьюсь головой о стену", ни как не пойму что делать! Собрался писать в программе консоль, но для этого нужен ввод строки которую я никак не пойму как сделать! Программа постоянно в цикле работает, _getch() не подходит ибо программа не должна прерываться на вводе текста, да и вообще главное окно не консоли а графическое окно! Окно я делаю через SFML внутренними возможностями получается криво, так как когда начитаешь вводить с клавиатуры текст, любое лишнее движение мышкой или ещё чего, то текст перестаёт писаться. Пожалуйста помогите. Возможно есть библиотека позволяющая нормально узнавать какая клавиша сейчас нажата или есть нормальные встроенные средства для этого?

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть 2 варианта

1. Кроссплатформенный - использовать для этих целей какую то библиотеку
   для этих целей (например Gainput)
2. Платформозависимый - использовать
   функции ОС для работы с вводом (GetKeyState для Windows)

И да так как SFML создает своё окно то getch бы все равно не словил бы нажатия клавиш, так как работает только с консольным окном

Answer (score 0):

Внутренних возможностей SFML вполне достаточно для получения информации о нажатых клавишах - [туториал](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-inputs.php).